# Waiting for a background thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

What's the difference between:

```cs
public class Worker
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        ExecuteInBackgroundThread().Wait();
    }

    private static Task ExecuteInBackgroundThread()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // do some long running operation
        });
    }
}
```

and

```cs
public class Worker
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        ExecuteInBackgroundThread().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task ExecuteInBackgroundThread()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // do some long running operation
        });
    }
}
```

I noticed that calling the second version of `Worker.Execute()` from the UI thread my Windows Phone app gets stuck.

Instead, using the first version everything seems to work fine.

Is the second version of `ExecuteInBackgroundThread` actually returning a `Task<T>` that can be awaited? But if that is not the case, should the compiler not give an error saying that we are not returning anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what calling `Execute` for each version does:

The first version calls `ExecuteInBackgroundThread` which immediately returns a `Task`. Then `Execute` blocks until the returned task is finished.

The second version calls `ExecuteInBackgroundThread` which creates a `Task` and schedules a continuation which will be executed when the task if finished, and returns another task. Then `Execute` blocks until the returned task is finished.

The difference is that the second version has a continuation scheduled because of the await keyword. The effect of it depends on the synchronization context of the thread in which you call `Execute`. When you are on a UI thread the second version will deadlock, because the continuation is scheduled on the UI thread which is blocked because of the call to `Wait`.

If you are using a console application then there won't be a deadlock because the default synchronization context uses the thread pool to execute the continuations.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed noticed that there was no deadlock running it from a test runner.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the real reason your app gets stuck is that you have a deadlock. That's because you're using `Task.Wait` which is blocking the UI thread on a task that is waiting for the UI Thread to complete.

That happens because there's only a single UI thread and so there's a `SynchronizationContext` that only uses that specific thread.

You can fix your deadlock by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which doesn't use the `SynchronizationContext`:

```
private static async Task<T> ExecuteInBackgroundThread<T>()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // do some long running operation
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Other than that, both options are pretty much the same as long as there's no more code in `ExecuteInBackgroundThread` which is outside of the call to `Task.Run`. The first option is slightly faster because you're using the task from Task.Run directly. The second option adds another redundant async layer (including a state machine, etc.) on top.

Conclusion: You should use the first option. But don't use `Wait` which not only blocks your threads, but may result in a deadlock in some cases.

Comment: The reason I am using `Wait()` is because this is done only once at app start-up and it's called from `App.xaml.cs`. This initialises a database and needs to be done before anything else is executed.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori Isn't there an Application.Load event? just put that code in the earliest event handler and make it async void.

Comment: I also think that the difference pointed out by Dirk is a good one. I think there's no deadlock in the first version as the UI thread just waits for the created task to finish. The only downside is that the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori The UI thread waits for the created task to finish in both cases (i.e. `Wait()`). Both Dirk and I are pointing at the same difference, but with different explanations.

Comment: Of course it does. But the first case does not create a continuation task, which is what generates the deadlock I believe.

Comment: So in the first case the UI thread is actually waiting for the task scheduled in the new thread, in the second case the UI thread is waiting for the continuation task that is scheduled on the UI thread, which is blocked waiting for itself. So I would say there is a big difference between the two.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori The thing that's responsible for the deadlock is the single threaded SynchronizationContext. Where there is none (e.g. console app) or when you don't use it (i.e ConfigureAwait(false)) there won't be one.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori calling it a continuation task is an over simplification. In the second case the UI is blocked on the task that is generated by marking `ExecuteInBackgroundThread` with the async keyword. That task "includes" the `Task.Run` task and the rest of the method (which in this case is nothing but the synchronization context part)